# How to align a View to center without changing children's position?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

```
<View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
   {OtherContent}
   <ScrollView>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', padding: 20}}>
           {children}
      </View>
   <ScrollView> 
</View>
```

I want the `View` inside `ScrollView` to be in center of the screen without changing it's children position

**Children:**

```
<View style={Styles.docsContainer}>
            {arr.map((document, index) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={[Style.docStyle} onPress={null}>
                        <Icon name='file-text-o'/>
                        <Text>{document.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            })}
</View>
const Styles: {
    docsContainer: {
       flexDirection: 'row',
       flexWrap: 'wrap',
       padding: 20,
    },
    docStyle: {
      alignItems: 'center', 
      padding: 20,
      margin: 5,
      marginBottom: 10,
      borderRadius: 8,
      width: 170
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you please draw the layout that what you want?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, we don't need parent View, we just need scrollView as flewGrow 1 which makes scrollView have full height and width as per device.

My approach:

```
   <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <View style={{
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flex: 1,
    }}>
      <Text>mahesh nandam</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

Try this.

Comment: I have some other content inside my parent `View`  other than `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

The `View`is your `ScrollView`'s immediate children. So you can style `ScrollView` using `contentContainerStyle` and align it in *center* like this.

```
<View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
    <ScrollView
         contentContainerStyle={{
             flexGrow: 1,
             justifyContent: 'center',
             alignItems: 'center',
         }}
    >
     <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', padding: 20}}>
         {children}
     </View>
    <ScrollView> 
</View>
```

I guess it's what you're loooking for.

Comment: `View` inside `ScrollView` is occupying 100% height and width. So unable to align to center as per your styling. Is there any way to shrink the `View` according to it's content?

Comment: You can try the same styling for `View` too. Or better you can avoid using it and give those styles directly to `ScrollView` via style prop.

Comment: If I apply same styling to `View` , Children inside the view, will be disturbed which I don't want to be happened. If I apply the styling to `ScrollView` via style prop, getting an error that **`ScrollView` child layout must be applied through the `contentContainerStyle` prop**

Comment: In my answer I've used `contentContainerStyle` only, Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I have done so. But no effect. That is what I have explained in first comment. I assume that if we can shrink the `View`  according to it's content , Then we can align it to center.

Answer (score 1):

**Center Horizontally**

If you only want to center the `View` horizontally, you can set `alignItems: 'center'` to `ScrollView`'s `contentContainerStyle`.

```
<View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
  <Text>Other content</Text>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', padding: 20, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <Text>children</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView> 
</View>
```

The inner `View` is highlighted in red.

[image: center horizontally]

**Center Horizontally and Vertically**

In this case, you can set `{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }` for the same `contentContainerStyle`.

```
<View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
  <Text>Other content</Text>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', padding: 20, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <Text>children</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView> 
</View>
```

[image: center horizontally and vertically]

If what you expect is different layout than in either of the screenshots, please share a simple sketch of the layout.

Comment: Yes, This is what I want to achieve and I had already tired this styling. But no effect since my children view is occupying full screen. So unable to align to center.

Comment: @Kishore do you mean `{children}` in your code? In that case, why do you want to center a full screen item? Are you looking for a way to shrink it by setting a style on parent view? If the question is more about the children, can post some code of the children components?

Comment: Yes, I want the Children `View` to be shrinked. So that it can be movable. And Please have a look at edited question for children code

Comment: @Kishore I'm still trying to understand the problem completely. What prevents you from setting a width or height on `styles.docsContainer`?

Comment: I set the `width: '90%', height: '100%'`. This time `View` moved to the center of the screen. But since i gave some specific width `View` didn't shrink according to it's content by leaving some extra space inside `View` and still content doesn't seem like in center. So I am looking for a styling that can shrink the `View' exactly according to it's content without leaving any spaces inside `View`